# Facing issues after migrating my current Project to mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I created my complete project in django with default(sqlite3) database and it was working fine....
Now I wish to change my database backend to mongoDB, so I used [Djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)
to translate my Django ORM models and queries to mongoDB document Queries

I made following changes to settings.py

```
# changing database to mongoDATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'djongo',
    'NAME': 'mongo_backend',
}
```

}

Now when I deleted all of my migration files and migrated changes again, Everything goes good and database `mongo_backend` is created in mongodb with all of my models as Collections.

Most of things works fine, But there are certain issues

1. `modles.PositiveIntegerField` which I was using for storing 10 digits phone number it raises validation error like `Ensure this value is less than or equal to 2147483647.`
2. when I try adding user through admin interface I get `NotImplementedError at /admin/auth/user/add/
   UNKNOWN command not implemented for SQL SAVEPOINT "s140684618393344_x1"`

models.py(schema)

```
class MyModel(models):
     mobile_no  = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Is there anything which I am missing while migrating my project to mongoDB?

Note : 
1.The only change in my models.py is that instead of inheriting models from `django.db.models` I am inheriting them from `djongo.models`
2.I am using python 3.6.7, mongodb v4.0.10 and 2.2.1

Comment: Well don't use integer fields for storing phone numbers. Why would you do that? They're not integers, they're strings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman But,why can't I store integer in mongoDB with value greater then `2147483647`?

Comment: @JayeshSingh because the integer is a 32bit length, you need to use the long number (a.k.a. big integer) which is a 64bit length. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong

Comment: @Neodan so how can I pass long int to mongoDb from django models fields(is there and specific field for that)

Comment: @Neodan checkout updates

Comment: @JayeshSingh try to use `models.BigIntegerField` instead of `models.IntegerField`